# Координаты курсора в консоли

Tags: visual-c++

Как в c++ visual studio вернуть текущие значение координат курсора в консоли? Желательно привести пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как таковой "консоли" с курсором в стандартном С++ нет. Есть стандартный поток вывода - такой же, как и в файл: какой курсор в файле?...

Но вы можете воспользоваться [функциями Windows API для консоли](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) - создавать ее, работать с ней - там можно воспользоваться функцией `GetConsoleCursorInfo`.